# How to decode obfuscated lua

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

Recently I downloaded a clientside script with a backdoor. How can i deobfuscate it?

```
local ‪ = _G local ‪‪ = ‪['string'] local ‪‪‪ = ‪['bit']['bxor'] local function ‪‪‪‪‪‪‪(‪‪‪‪) if ‪‪['len'](‪‪‪‪) == 0 then return ‪‪‪‪ end local ‪‪‪‪‪ = '' for _ in ‪‪['gmatch'](‪‪‪‪,'..') do ‪‪‪‪‪=‪‪‪‪‪..‪‪['char'](‪‪‪(‪["tonumber"](_,16),238)) end return ‪‪‪‪‪ end local ‪‪false=‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'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' ‪[‪‪‪‪‪‪‪'bc9b80bd9a9c878089'](‪‪false)
```

Here is while without 'end'

Comment: Start with replacing invisible characters with visible letters: `s = s:gsub("\226\128\170", "x")`

Comment: [deobfuscated](https://pastebin.com/LNgwZUQV)